# Convert from PowerShell to C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

The was a problem with Exchange in C#.

I need to convert this PowerShell command:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Where-Object {$_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning -eq $false} | select Name,DatabaseSize | sort DatabaseSize
```

I tried the following code, but it gives an System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException

```
PSCommand command1 = new PSCommand();
            command1.AddCommand("Get-MailboxDatabase");
            command1.AddParameter("Status");
            command1.AddCommand("Where-Object");
            command1.AddArgument("IsExcludedFromProvisioning");
            command1.AddParameter("eq", false);
            command1.AddCommand("select-object").AddParameter("Property", new string[] { "Name", "DatabaseSize" });
            command1.AddCommand("sort-object").AddParameter("Property", "DatabaseSize");
            PowershellExchange.Commands = command1;
            PowershellExchange.Runspace = RunspaceExchange;
            var tmp1 = PowershellExchange.Invoke();
```

Tell me, what could be the problem, or how can you alternatively rewrite the powershell command?

**Edit**

Inner Exception: The specified operator requires both the -Property parameter and the -Value parameter. Specify values ​​for both parameters and run the command again.

Comment: Please update the question with your error :-)

Comment: The argument to `Where-Object` is a scriptblock. You are effectively passing the moral equivalent of `Where-Object IsExcludedFromProvisioning -eq false`, where `-eq` is a parameter rather than an operator -- altogether a completely different thing. You're probably better off with `AddScript` to add the whole statement instead of building it piecemeal (no variables appear to be involved here).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, i try your advice, i replace Where-Object block to `command1.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create("Where-Object $_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning"));
command1.AddParameter("eq", false);`. Command is work, but return empty collection. If i enter my PowerShell command in Powershell, they return 10 lines with data.

Comment: Because `AddParameter("eq", false)` is still wrong. This is *not* a parameter, it's invoking the `-eq` operator. Do you have moral problems with using `AddScript`? That's a whole lot simpler than effectively doing the parsing yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, now i use `command1.AddScript("Where-Object $_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning -eq $false"); ` and command also return empty collection. Also i try use script with full powershell command and they also return empty collection

Comment: The idea is `.AddScript("Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Where-Object {$_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning -eq $false} | select Name,DatabaseSize | sort DatabaseSize")`. If that returns nothing, go back to basics (try `.AddScript("Get-MailboxDatabase -Status")` and then `.AddScript("Write-Output 'Hi'")` to verify that you can actually get *any* results. If that works but the Exchange script doesn't, you'll need to investigate the difference between starting PowerShell manually and however you create the PowerShell session in C#.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thanks a lot, i finally figured out, i write final code in answer

Comment: If your code is C#, why do you want to wrap powershell commands? Wan't you use more "straightforward" ways to call Exchange from C# code (Exchange Web Service for example)

Comment: @SteveB, because legacy code written with scripts both Powershell and C#, and rewrite legacy code in clear c# is more difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jeroen Mostert for help

Final code looks like

```
PSCommand command1 = new PSCommand();
                command1.AddScript("Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Where-Object {$_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning -eq $false} | select Name,DatabaseSize | sort DatabaseSize");
                PowershellExchange.Commands = command1;
                PowershellExchange.Runspace = RunspaceExchange;
                var tmp1 = PowershellExchange.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem counter-intuitive, but in the following:

```
... |Where-Object Something -eq $SomeValue
```

`-eq` is a actually a switch parameter, and the verbose form of this would be:

```
... |Where-Object -Property:Something -Eq:$true -Value:$SomeValue
```

So, to re-create the `Where-Object` pipeline element without a filter scriptblock:

```
command1.AddCommand("Where-Object")
        .AddParameter("Property", "IsExcludedFromProvisioning")
        .AddParameter("Eq", true)
        .AddParameter("Value", false);
```

Comment: no, this not help.
The problem is that $_.IsExcludedFromProvisioning it is not property.
I read that $_. somthing like PSItem

Comment: @ishkin `Where-Object Something -eq $SomeValue` is functionally equivalent to `Where-Object {$_.Something -eq $SomeValue}`